# Review audit failure for editing a low quality question?

Tags: bug, specific-question, review-audit

I just failed [a review audit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/1013792) by attempting to **edit** the question, which turned out to be low quality.

Strangely enough, the system message says that I failed because I was **upvoting** it (which I did not).

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You
>   didn't pass. This post was of very poor quality, and needed
>   significant improvements to be useful – upvoting such posts hurts the
>   ability of others to find and answer good questions. Please try to fix
>   such posts by editing, downvoting, closing, or flagging as "very low
>   quality".
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance above.

The message itself is contradictory and even says `Please try to fix such posts by editing, ...`

Is this a bug? Or why is editing a low quality question a failure?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what edit did you want to make to the Question?  Would it supply some context?

Comment: Questions that are selected for the audit are supposed to be of an extremely low quality, and the consensus is that you're not supposed to be upvoting such questions, I think that's what it means. The quality of a question may always be debatable, but then again failing an audit is not the end of the world. Just try and do your best when reviewing.

Comment: Oh I thought that you were implicitly saying that you had upvoted it as well. Nevermind. It may be that the audit feedback is the same for a number of different actions, just like the comments left to OPs from review. Or it could be a bug indeed.

Comment: Typically, clicking on "edit" a low-quality or closed post does not yield a failed audit.  My best guess is that perhaps you "mis-clicked" (trust me, I've done that, a few times), even when I intended to click otherwise.  I'm not saying that you did mis-click, but it is a possibility to consider; else, I can only surmise there was a glitch, or a "bug", but I've never failed an audit for an attempt to edit.

Comment: [Seems a bug, according to Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368118/2821954).

Comment: Nice find, @AndrewT.

Comment: @AndrewT. You should post that as an answer so that this question does not remain unanswered.